# Counting words on a html web page using php

Tags: php, html, scripting, bots

I need a PHP script which takes a URL of a web page and then echoes how many times a word is mentioned.

### Example

**This is a generic HTML page:**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> This is the title </h1>
<p> some description text here, <b>this</b> is a word. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**This will be the PHP script:**

```
<?php
htmlurl="generichtml.com";
the script here
echo(result);
?>
```

So the output will be a table like this:

```
WORDS       Mentions
This        2
is          2
the         1
title       1
some        1
description 1
text        1
a           1
word        1
```

This is something like the search bots do when they are surfing the web, so, any idea of how to begin, or even better, do you have a PHP script which already does this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The one line below will do a case insensitive word count after stripping all HTML tags from your string.

[**Live Example**](http://codepad.org/4KI2ub5p)

```
print_r(array_count_values(str_word_count(strip_tags(strtolower($str)), 1)));
```

To grab the source code of a page you can use [**cURL**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [**file_get_contents()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

From inside out:

1. Use [**strtolower()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to make everything lower case.
2. Strip HTML tags using [**strip_tags()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)
3. Create an array of words used using [**str_word_count()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php). The argument `1`  returns an array containing all the words found inside the string.
4. Use [**array_count_values()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to capture words used more than once by counting the occurrence of each value in your array of words.
5. Use [**print_r()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to display the results.

Comment: Well yeah, but how 'bout `script` and `style` tags?

Comment: @Yi Jiang - If you want to deal with those separately, many HTML parsers already exist. There's no point in rewriting one, since they are fussy and complicated beasts.

Answer (score 5):

The below script will read the contents of the remote url, remove the html tags, and count the occurrences of each unique word therein.

Caveat: In your expected output, "This" has a value of 2, but the below is case-sensitive, so both "this" and "This" are recorded as separate words. You coudl convert the whole input string to lower case before processing if the original case is not significant for your purposes.

Additionally, as only a basic strip_tags is run on the input, mal-formed tags will not be removed, so the assumption is that your source html is valid.

**Edit:** Charlie points out in the comments that things like the `head` section will still be counted. With the help of a function defined in the [user notes of the strip_tags function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#68757), these are also now taken care of.

**generichtml.com**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> This is the title </h1>
<p> some description text here, <b>this</b> is a word. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**parser.php**

```
// Fetch remote html
$contents = file_get_contents($htmlurl);

// Get rid of style, script etc
$search = array('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',  // Strip out javascript
           '@<head>.*?</head>@siU',            // Lose the head section
           '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
           '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments including CDATA
);

$contents = preg_replace($search, '', $contents); 

$result = array_count_values(
              str_word_count(
                  strip_tags($contents), 1
                  )
              );

print_r($result);
```

?>

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [This] => 1
    [is] => 2
    [the] => 1
    [title] => 1
    [some] => 1
    [description] => 1
    [text] => 1
    [here] => 1
    [this] => 1
    [a] => 1
    [word] => 1
)
```

Comment: This is a clean solution but style and script tag content still exist. Than all the head of the page should be removed.

Comment: If you use the regExpressions not valid html code could be analyzed ;)
Punctuation is still a problem

Comment: Please don't parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: btw, strip_tags() (which you use) already removes multi line HTML comments and CDATA - http://codepad.org/gpdden0T http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php .

Answer (score 1):

That is my code for counting words containing html tags:

```
$sayilacak_metin = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $sayilacak_metin);
$sayilacak_metin = preg_replace("/<([^>]*(<|$))/", "&lt;$1", $sayilacak_metin);
$sayilacak_metin = strip_tags($sayilacak_metin);
$sayilacak_metin = str_replace(chr(194)," ",$sayilacak_metin);
$sayilacak_metin = str_replace(chr(160)," ",$sayilacak_metin);
$sayilacak_metin = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\r\t\n]/','/\r/','/\t/','/\n/'), ' ', $sayilacak_metin);
$sayilacak_metin=trim($sayilacak_metin);
$parca = explode(" ", $sayilacak_metin);
$sonuc=count(array_filter($parca));
```

- Step1: Convert all nbsp to space
- Step2: Fix broken html tags (If not fixed striptags function will broke string)
- Step3: Strip html tags
- Step4&5&6: Clear hidden whitespaces and new line/tabs
- Step7:Trim beginning and end of string
- Step8:Convert every word to array
- Step9:Count Filtered Array

Comment: 2 comments: a) if there is no whitespace between tags e.g `<h1>title</h1><p>lolo</p>` then strip_tags will result in `titlelolo`, one way would be adding space after each tag b) there is also php function `str_word_count` - you use that instead of 2nd `preg_replace` until `$parca`

Answer (score 0):

The previous code is a point where start. The next step is delete html tags with the regular expressions. Look for ereg and eregi functions. Some other tricks are required for style and script tags (you have to remove the content)
Points and commas have to be removed too...

Comment: `ereg`'s been deprecated and, to begin with, regexes are not an adequate tool for parsing arbitrary HTML.

Comment: How can regular expression be deprecated if they exist from perl O.O?

Comment: Answers are not always listed in chronological order on SO, so `previous code` isn't very helpful. A url link (each answer has a unique one) or author reference is better.

Comment: Regular expressions haven't been deprecated, only the ereg extension. Use PCRE instead (the `preg_` function family).

Answer (score -1):

This is a complex job that you should not attempt on your own.

You have to extract text that is not part of tags/comments and is not a child for elements such as `script` and `style`. For this, you'll also need a lax HTML parser (like the one implemented in libxml2 and used in `DOMDocument`.

Then you have to [tokenize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenize) the text, which presents its own challenges. Finally, you'd interested in some form of [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) before proceeding to counting the terms.

I recommend you use specialized tools for this. I haven't used any of these, but you can try [HTMLParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) for parsing and [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) for tokenization/stemming (the purpose of Lucene is [Text Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_retrieval), but those operations are necessary for building the index).

Comment: A complex job? The ConroyP code works well and does a big part of what you listed. HTML has a very regular syntax

Comment: @Charlie There's so many things that are missing... Dealing with encodings that are not ASCII, proper handling of HTML (I could easily build an HTML document with a bible transcription that would yield him no words whatsoever for his code), a proper tokenizer (`str_word_count` is very basic and only handles ASCII), a stemmer, ...

Comment: A stemmer? Fist why add a stemmer that will not be able to find the roots of every languages? (what is the purpose? The original question asked for a simple HTML parser, not a language analyzer)

Comment: You can [find](http://snowball.tartarus.org/) stemmers for several languages. The OP dind't say he want stemming, but it's legitimate to assume he wants, esp since there's already some form of term normalization in his question ("This" and "this" are counted as the same). And I suppose you concede the other points...

Comment: Yes, my doubts are still on the stemmer. You the Italian on the list you signaled doesn't correctly match to 30% of Italian words, and the vocabulary it contains is just the 1% of Italian words (I'm not kidding). Martin Porter has written an algorithm good for English (perhaps) but not good for other more complex languages.