# i need help for counting word inside a web page source code by using php

Tags: php, html, url, web-crawler

How can I count words in URL source code by using php?

EX:

```
<body><p>hello</p>
<h1>hello</h1>
<h2>hello</h2>
<p>there</p>
```

I want counting word (hello)

so the outout must be 
hello = 3 word;

Comment: [Similar question also aking here take a look][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485673/counting-words-on-a-html-web-page-using-php

Comment: So you know in advance which word you need to count? If you show the code you've attempted it will clarify what your issue is, and it will show that you're not completely lazy and tried to figure it out yourself. Should "hellohello" be counted as 2 hellos or 0?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [substr_count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) function:

```
echo substr_count($html, 'hello');
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It does exactly what he asks!! quote: i want counting word (hello)

so the outout must be hello = 3 word; Please remove your misguided downvote

Comment: @user574632 it'll also match worldhello, helloworld, etc

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It counts occurrences of a string, whether or not they are "words" is a separate issue.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I don't think that's what the OP is going for.OP is asking for words NOT string.

Comment: @Himal All we know for sure is "*i want counting word (hello)*". Shoud this match "foohello" or "hellobar"... I have no idea. The post is vague so I voted to close it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Exactly.that's why 'substr_count()' won't help in this case.see my first comment in this answer.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: `i need help for counting word`, `how i can counting word`, etc.

Comment: The OP not clarify this, you are just speculating. I dont belive that is worth a downvote

Comment: @user574632: _I_ downvoted because this does not require clarifying. It is crystal clear and your answer is therefore wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Whatever, the question clearly sucks and answering it while it's incomplete is helpful to pretty much no one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know you downvoted, and i completely disagree that the OP's question is clear about this. "word" is pretty ambiguous as the Ops english is not strong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and my answer gives his expected output(3). Downvoting on speculations is wrong

Comment: @user574632 Answering based on speculation is similar. If you stand behind your answer then just carry on.

Comment: Your answer gives expected output for like 20 out of many millions of possible inputs. If he only wanted it to work for this exact input then he would simply hardcode the result "3". No, this is still not a solution.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it gives expected output for posted input. the remaining millions of POSSIBLE inputs that he does not mention or hint at whatsoever have no bearing on my answer. Probably you have GUESSED correctly, but downvoting on guess is unfair

Comment: You're not listening to me whatsoever. I give up with you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ditto. Im listening, and i except that you are probably correct, but with no clarification from the OP we are both guessing. You guess he wants to count occurrences of the exact word 'hello'. I guess he would be happy with instances of the string 'hello'. Neither of us know the answer. I maintain that a downvote should not be based on speculation.

Comment: No, and I'll say it _once again_, I'm not "guessing" or "speculating" at anything. It is an objective fact that you have posted a fundamentally non-robust solution. Whether the OP needs more than that, well, frankly I don't care — this is a Q&A not a personal helpdesk and answers are expected to help other people in the future. This one will lead people astray.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo substr_count(file_get_contents("http://hellowood.eu/"),"hello");
```

Output:

```
11
```

Comment: Wrong for the same reason that the existing answer saying the same thing is wrong.