# WordPress: Excerpt after text but before images

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wondering how to do the following:

I want to do an excerpt after 45 words, but if the text of the post is less than 45 words and images are included in the post, then the more tag should be included right after the text.

1st: I would be happy with this solution.
2nd: Great might be to have in such a case an alternative sentence, e.g. "Click to see pictures.".

Hope this makes sense to anybody reading this.

Currently I have the following:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Sets the post excerpt length to 15 characters.
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function moka_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 45;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'moka_excerpt_length' );


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Returns a "Continue Reading" link for excerpts
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function moka_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '&hellip; <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __( 'Read more', 'moka' ) . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'moka_excerpt_more' );
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: You need to look in your theme template files. If you want to edit the excerpts for your index.php, then you can do an if / else on that page.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. How would an if /else look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think, You can write the code yourself.
You can add filter to the_content() or an alternative way:
Refer to this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/executing-a-function-only-if-a-post-contains-an-image, you can check if the_content() has img or no?!
And for counting words in the_content() this answer is useful:
[Counting words on a html web page using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485673/counting-words-on-a-html-web-page-using-php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot write the code myself. My knowledge is less than basic.

I just want to enhance the Wordpress more link, checking if a picture is included when the words are less than 45 in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I did some deeper research and came up with the following. I know that it won't work, but some parts work as standalone, but I am not able to bring everything together. Maybe somebody can help to point me into the right direction?

```
    function individual_excerpt_more( $more ) {
if {
    function word_count() {
        $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
        $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
        return $word_count; <45 // (less than 45 words)
        }
    && $content = $post->post_content;
    if( has_shortcode( $content, 'gallery', 'video' ) ) {
    // The content has a [gallery] & [video] short code, so this check returned true.
    }
    return '&hellip; <ins><a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Read more</a></ins>';
    }
else {
    function theme_excerpt_length( $length ) {
        return 45;
    }
    add_filter( 'excerpt_length', ’theme_excerpt_length' );
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'individual_excerpt_more' );
```